# Retrieve rendered graphics via WSTP

Tags: programming, mathlink-or-wstp, interoperability

I am planning on using *Mathematica* as calculation and rendering backend for an application, i.e., call *Mathematica* via WSTP and use `EvaluatePacket` to have it evaluate commands.

However, I'm not sure how to go about retrieving rendered graphics, e.g. the output of a `Plot`, in a ready-to-use format like PNG or any other output format *Mathematica* supports.

How can I

- Tell *Mathematica* the desired output format?
- Retrieve the (usually binary) data via WSTP (`ReturnPacket` inspection)?

J/Link and NETLink do this with ease, but I would require a solution running from pure WSTP, i.e. using C++.

What would be the best way to proceed?

Comment: Either return a 2D byte array to represent the image, or return a string containing the PNG file.  You'll need to convert to these formats on the Mathematica side, e.g. `ExportString[..., "PNG"]` or `Rasterize` to get the array.

Comment: Thanks! I will go in that direction. However, I am unsure, if a binary exported as string will do well on the C++ side, since there may well be binary zeros, so that the C++ string would get truncated prematurely.

Comment: When you retrieve a string through MathLink, it's not assumed to be zero-terminated. Most MathLink functions will tell you the number of bytes it has instead. Not sure off-hand which is the right function to use, so you'll need too search the docs a bit.  `MLGetByteString` maybe?